# What is a good DB for Offline/Online capabilities for a Web Application

Tags: database, angular, offlineapps

My team is developing an appraisals software for real estate on an enterprise level. This application has some special requirements.

The application should work in Online and Offline environment. If the user is working and suddenly Application goes offline User should be able to work offline. All offline work is stored in local database and sync next time to a central database when Application connects to the internet.This application has many users and all will work at the same time on same information.

User local database must be updated all times either other users are working or not. If other users are working all updated information should be available in the local database to ensure when the user goes offline all information is updated.

The question is How to develop this kind of application? Is there any standard way to achieve this target? Is there any standard or non-standard pattern to build this kind of software?

We are planning to use the Angular 2 Framework for our front end development. If anyone has experience with this and can give suggestions on what tech stack we should use, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use pouchdb as client-side DB and use every DB that uses the CouchDB sync protocol. I have used this stack with an Angular 2 application. (NoSQL)

I also worked with Kinto (PostgreSQL) and Kinto.js. It is not as user-friendly as PouchDB, but I think the documentation has improved since I used it.

And finally, I know about Meteor/Mongo/GroundDB. Meteor is very powerful it's a fully reactive Stack which works really well with the async options you have with angular and rxjs. But think if you have not worked with rxjs or reactive backends it's the hardest to learn. I took me a long time to adapt my coding style to the reactive Behavior of the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

We are also doing an online POS that would work as a point of sale

but we are in constant backend solution for us to set up database that can sync or scale with offline and online .

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30440657)